# Android 2.3.3 Crashes - ImageView

Tags: android, memory, crash, imageview, android-2.3-gingerbread

The Image I am attempting to use is only 5.6kb
I am using the following code:

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

...

ImageView byreference = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.byreference);

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/byreference"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/byreference" />
```

I am getting the following error:

```
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.turbo/com.example.turbo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at com.example.turboverse.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:18)
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
12-31 03:50:30.835: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Check line number 18 of your MainActivity.java class.

Comment: You have a NullPointerException at line 18 in MainActivity.java. Some object reference is null on that line.

Comment: Try changing the id of the image view to something else

Comment: Put the code of your main activity here to better understand what's wrong.